# Proguard file not being read

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

Problem: Doesn't seem like the proguard file is being read.

Error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:assembleDebug, :NativeXPlugin:assembleDebug, 

:OneSignalConfig:assembleDebug, :answers:assembleDebug, :beta:assembleDebug, :cheetah-mobile:assembleDebug, :crashlytics:assembleDebug, :crashlytics-wrapper:assembleDebug, :fabric:assembleDebug, :fabric-init:assembleDebug]
Warning:com.adscendmedia.unity.SDKBridge$1: can't find superclass or interface com.adscendmedia.sdk.rest.video.RewardVideoListener
Warning:com.adscendmedia.unity.SDKBridge$2: can't find superclass or interface com.adscendmedia.sdk.util.CompletedOfferRequestListener
Warning:com.adscendmedia.unity.SDKBridge$3: can't find superclass or interface com.adscendmedia.sdk.util.ADOfferRequestListener
Warning:com.adscendmedia.unity.SDKBridge$4: can't find superclass or interface com.adscendmedia.sdk.util.JsonArrayRequestListener
Warning:com.adscendmedia.unity.SDKBridge$5: can't find superclass or interface com.adscendmedia.sdk.util.JsonArrayRequestListener
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialBannerProvider$1: can't find superclass or interface com.millennialmedia.InlineAd$InlineListener
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialBannerProvider$2: can't find superclass or interface com.millennialmedia.InlineAd$InlineAbortListener
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider$1: can't find superclass or interface com.millennialmedia.InterstitialAd$InterstitialListener
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkBannerProvider$1$1: can't find superclass or interface com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView$BannerAdListener
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkInterstitialProvider$1: can't find superclass or interface com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubInterstitial$InterstitialAdListener
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asrhythmonesdk.ASRhythmOneSdkInterstitialProvider$1: can't find superclass or interface com.rhythmone.ad.sdk.RhythmEventListener
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.astremor.ASTremorInterstitialProvider$1: can't find superclass or interface com.tremorvideo.sdk.android.videoad.TremorAdStateListener
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asunity.ASUnityInterstitialProvider: can't find superclass or interface com.unity3d.ads.android.IUnityAdsListener
Warning:com.appodeal.ads.a.u: can't find superclass or interface com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView$BannerAdListener
Warning:com.appodeal.ads.b.x: can't find superclass or interface com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubInterstitial$InterstitialAdListener
Warning:com.appodeal.ads.c.p: can't find superclass or interface com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView$BannerAdListener
Warning:com.appodeal.ads.e.p: can't find superclass or interface com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubInterstitial$InterstitialAdListener

Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialBannerProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InlineAd$InlineListener
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialBannerProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InlineAd$InlineErrorStatus
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialBannerProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InlineAd
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialBannerProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InlineAd$InlineErrorStatus
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialBannerProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InlineAd
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialBannerProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InlineAd$InlineErrorStatus
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialBannerProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InlineAd
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialBannerProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InlineAd$InlineAbortListener
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialBannerProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InlineAd
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.MMSDK
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.MMException
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.AppInfo
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.MMSDK
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.MMException
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InterstitialAd
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InterstitialAd$InterstitialAdMetadata
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InterstitialAd
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.MMException
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.AppInfo
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.MMSDK
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InterstitialAd
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InterstitialAd$InterstitialListener
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InterstitialAd
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.MMException
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.AppInfo
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InterstitialAd$InterstitialAdMetadata
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.MMException
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InterstitialAd$InterstitialErrorStatus
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InterstitialAd$InterstitialListener
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InterstitialAd$InterstitialErrorStatus
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InterstitialAd
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InterstitialAd$InterstitialErrorStatus
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InterstitialAd
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InterstitialAd$InterstitialErrorStatus
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InterstitialAd
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InterstitialAd$InterstitialErrorStatus
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InterstitialAd
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InterstitialAd$InterstitialErrorStatus
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmillennial.ASMillennialInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.millennialmedia.InterstitialAd
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkBannerProvider: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkBannerProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkBannerProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView$BannerAdListener
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkBannerProvider$1$1: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubErrorCode
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkBannerProvider$1$1: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView$BannerAdListener
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkBannerProvider$1$1: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubErrorCode
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkBannerProvider$1$1: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkBannerProvider$1$1: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubErrorCode
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkBannerProvider$1$1: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkBannerProvider$1$1: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubErrorCode
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkBannerProvider$1$1: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkBannerProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubInterstitial
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubInterstitial$InterstitialAdListener
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubInterstitial
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubErrorCode
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubInterstitial$InterstitialAdListener
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubErrorCode
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubInterstitial
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubErrorCode
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubInterstitial
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubErrorCode
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asmopubsdk.ASMoPubSdkInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubInterstitial
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asrhythmonesdk.ASRhythmOneSdkInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.rhythmone.ad.sdk.RhythmOneAd
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asrhythmonesdk.ASRhythmOneSdkInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.rhythmone.ad.sdk.RhythmEventListener
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asrhythmonesdk.ASRhythmOneSdkInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.rhythmone.ad.sdk.RhythmOneAd
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asrhythmonesdk.ASRhythmOneSdkInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.rhythmone.ad.sdk.RhythmEvent
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asrhythmonesdk.ASRhythmOneSdkInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.rhythmone.ad.sdk.RhythmEventListener
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asrhythmonesdk.ASRhythmOneSdkInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.rhythmone.ad.sdk.RhythmEvent
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asrhythmonesdk.ASRhythmOneSdkInterstitialProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.rhythmone.ad.sdk.RhythmOneAd
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asrhythmonesdk.ASRhythmOneSdkInterstitialProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.rhythmone.ad.sdk.RhythmEvent
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asrhythmonesdk.ASRhythmOneSdkInterstitialProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.rhythmone.ad.sdk.RhythmOneAd
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asrhythmonesdk.ASRhythmOneSdkInterstitialProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.rhythmone.ad.sdk.RhythmEvent
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asrhythmonesdk.ASRhythmOneSdkInterstitialProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.rhythmone.ad.sdk.RhythmEventListener
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asrhythmonesdk.ASRhythmOneSdkInterstitialProvider$2: can't find referenced class com.rhythmone.ad.sdk.RhythmEvent
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asrhythmonesdk.ASRhythmOneSdkInterstitialProvider$3: can't find referenced class com.rhythmone.ad.sdk.RhythmOneAd
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asrhythmonesdk.ASRhythmOneSdkInterstitialProvider$4: can't find referenced class com.rhythmone.ad.sdk.RhythmOneAd
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asrhythmonesdk.ASRhythmOneSdkInterstitialProvider$5: can't find referenced class com.rhythmone.ad.sdk.RhythmEvent
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.astremor.ASTremorInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.tremorvideo.sdk.android.videoad.TremorVideo
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.astremor.ASTremorInterstitialProvider$1: can't find referenced class com.tremorvideo.sdk.android.videoad.TremorAdStateListener
Warning:com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.asunity.ASUnityInterstitialProvider: can't find referenced class com.unity3d.ads.android.UnityAds
Warning:there were 479 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 10.838 secs
Information:1 error
Information:276 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Build Gradle:

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'animated-vector-drawable-23.4.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'appcompat-v7-23.4.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'cardview-v7-23.4.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'customtabs-23.4.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'facebook-android-wrapper-7.9.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'onesignal-unity', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-ads-10.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-ads-lite-10.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-base-10.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-basement-10.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-clearcut-10.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-gass-10.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-gcm-10.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-iid-10.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-location-10.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-tasks-10.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'pollfish-googleplay-4.3.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'simple-android-notifications', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-v4-24.0.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-vector-drawable-23.4.0', ext:'aar')
    compile project(':answers')
    compile project(':beta')
    compile project(':cheetah-mobile')
    compile project(':crashlytics')
    compile project(':crashlytics-wrapper')
    compile project(':fabric')
    compile project(':fabric-init')
    compile project(':NativeXPlugin')
    compile project(':OneSignalConfig')

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    signingConfigs { release {
        storeFile file('C:/Users/Josh/Desktop/KidKiwiKeyStore.keystore')
        storePassword ''
        keyAlias ''
        keyPassword ''
    } }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            jniDebuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

I have a proguard-unity.txt file in my root folder, but it doesn't seem to be read when I build an apk. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you say it's not being read? Also you should disable minification in the debug build and set debuggable to false in the release build.

Comment: @M.Sameer because of all the warning I get. Right, i'm actually testing minification, so that's why it's in debug.

Comment: It's normal to get warning when proguard file is being read properly :) .. we solve these warning one by one by adding more lines to the proguard file. try for example adding `-dontwarn com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.**` and see if some of the warning above will go away.

Comment: @M.Sameer Thanks for that, it helped! Any idea how to solve this error: Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\gradle\Finak\CashPal\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\debug\jars\3\1f\main.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\gradle\Finak\CashPal\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\CashPal\cheetah-mobile\unspecified\jars\libs\cheetah-mobile.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [cheetah-mobile.jar:com/cmcm/adsdk/BuildConfig.class]))

Seems to be the BuildConfig

Comment: Are you using Google Endpoints ?

Comment: I also converted the comment to an answer.

Comment: @m.sameer no I do not

Comment: I am not familiar with that library .. see if hey have specific instructions for proguard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal to get warning when proguard file is being read properly :) .. we solve these warning one by one by adding more lines to the proguard file. try for example adding :

`-dontwarn com.aerserv.sdk.adapter.**`

and see if some of the warning above will go away.